# How to change encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-8-BOM of exported *.txt files from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, encoding, utf-8

Exported text files from Excel are encoded with UTF-8.

An encoding UTF-8-BOM is needed.

I think that in code shall be inserted a row, written like:

Java

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?

[Jasperreport CSV UTF-8 without BOM instead of UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037404/jasperreport-csv-utf-8-without-bom-instead-of-utf-8)

or

HTML5

meta charset="utf-8"

[Bad UTF-8 without BOM encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102935/bad-utf-8-without-bom-encoding)

```
Sub export_data()
Dim row, column, i, j As Integer
Dim fullPath, myFile As String

fullPath = "C:\Workspace"
row = 21
column = 5

For i = 1 To column
    myFile = Cells(1, i).Value + ".txt"
    myFile = fullPath + "/" + myFile
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For j = 2 To row
        Print #1, Cells(j, i).Value
    Next j
    Close #1
Next i

End Sub
```

How can I define and where to put a row, which defines encoding UTF-8-BOM?
Thank You.

Comment: Wondering why you need the BOM?  Will you be importing into some other program that requires it?

Comment: Thank you for help.
Yes.
 I need to autogenerate  *.tex files for implementation into Context /Latex/.

I've found out, if an row:
...
    Const strCharset = "utf-8-bom"
 ...
is inserted, than file is ANSI encoded.

It is not solution but, step forward.

Comment: This code doesn't write the file using the UTF-8 character encoding. It uses the computer's user's current ANSI encoding (which is very likely not UTF-8). Can the consuming program not read an xlsx workbook? It is an open standard (Open XML SpreadsheetML). The problem with CSV is that it throws away tons of metadata that must then be communicated separately to follow-on readers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **Print**ing the file line by line, it might be more efficient to

- save your selected range as a `CSV UTF-8`

  - you might need to change the file type after saving
- Use ADO to process the file as UTF-8

Either will add a BOM automatically.

**EDIT**

If you are unfamiliar, you could perform the `save to csv - utf8` process manually with the macro recorder turned on.  Then examine what you have recorded and make appropriate edits.

Another way of adding the BOM, in the context of your existing code, would be to write it directly as a byte array to the first line.

For example:

```
Dim BOM(0 To 2) As Byte 'EF BB BF
    BOM(0) = &HEF
    BOM(1) = &HBB
    BOM(2) = &HBF

Open myFile For Binary Access Write As #1
    Put #1, 1, BOM
Close #1
```

will put the BOM at the beginning of the file.
You should then change the mode in your subsequent `Print` code to `Append`.

I suggest you read about the pros and cons of using `Print` vs `Write`

You should also read about declaration statements.  In yours, only the last variable on each line is being declared as the specified type; the preceding variables are being implicitly declared as being of type Variant.

Comment: I am illiterate in programming.

The code has written by Jugal Shah

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149532/export-excel-columns-into-multiple-text-files

I need multiple files. It is ok, if *.csv files are generated with appropriate encoding. I will rename them with "Bulk Rename Utility".

Can You help me to change code from Print to Save into files?

Comment: If you are illiterate in programming, you won't be able to maintain your code, so you should give serious thought to hiring a professional to do that.  But see my edit for some other ideas.